# How to upload more then 50 mp .mp3 files with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I am new to php and i want solution for **large mp3 upload into php server**.

I am using this way to upload mp3 file but getting issue when i upload large file.
Code:

```
$mp3=$_FILES['upload_file']['name'] ;
    $folder="../songs";\
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"],$folder."/".$mp3);
    $path = $folder."/".$mp3;
```

Please give me guideline or snippet to upload mp3 file.

Comment: check `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`

Comment: @gbestard i changes that limit but not getting success.

Comment: look at Manwal's answer, you also need to change the value of `post_max_size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change values in your `php.ini`

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M
```

> **Note:** You need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

You can also do this with `.htaccess` file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M
```

You can also use [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

[More details](http://bavotasan.com/2012/increase-max-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/)

Comment: If you dont have access to `php.ini` (on some hostings) try `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');` and `ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');`.

Comment: Yes @Wampirue added info in answer. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Manwal where i can put ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M'); and ini_set('post_max_size', '50M'); this?

Comment: @AnkurBusa Instead of saying "thanks for the help" you should accept this answer